# how to bind an <span> in an <canvas> javascript to get mathematic formulas

Tags: javascript, canvas, katex

I have an little problem to understand how i could implement an formula out of an existing KaTex Js file in an canvas element to get the same symbols as i get it with

```
<span id="mykatex1">...</span>
<script>
  katex.render("f(a,b,c) = (a^2+b^2+c^2)^3", mykatex1);
</script>
```

.But i want the possition of the < span > in the

```
ctx.fillText( "-A", p_index_a, p_index_a );
```

sector, where

```
 "-A"
```

is. ...
And thats my problem. Maybe it exists an other way how to implement math functions in an canvas area, but atm i am a little bit confused and planless how i could handle that. By the way. Thats an full functional blank dynamic graph. Free for use. An solution wouldbe cool, because the plan is to implement also the same symbols in the graph area. thx

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
  <title>Simple guide to using KaTeX</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/js_formeln__katex.min.css">
  <script src="js/katex.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    canvas {
      border: 1px solid black;
      font: 1.2em "Fira Sans", sans-serif;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p><span id="mykatex1">...</span></p>
  <script>
    katex.render("f(a,b,c) = (a^2+b^2+c^2)^3", mykatex1);
  </script>
  <body onload="draw();">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="2000" height="1000" ></canvas>
</body>

<script>
  function draw() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    if (canvas.getContext) {

    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var b_x = 300, b_y = 300;
    var b_x_erweitern_um = 600;
    var b_y_erweitern_um = 100;
    var x = 0, y = 0;
    var grid_breite_x_y = 10;
    var linewidth_1 = 0.1 , linewidth_2 = 1;
    var freier_oberer_rand = 10;
    var nach_links_verkleinern = 0;
    var nach_rechts_verkleinern = 500;
    var d_in = 0.5;

    for ( x ; x <= b_x - freier_oberer_rand - nach_links_verkleinern - 
      nach_rechts_verkleinern + b_x_erweitern_um ; x += grid_breite_x_y ) {
      ctx.moveTo( d_in + x + freier_oberer_rand + nach_rechts_verkleinern , freier_oberer_rand );
      ctx.lineWidth = linewidth_1;
      ctx.lineTo( d_in + x + freier_oberer_rand + nach_rechts_verkleinern , b_x + b_y_erweitern_um);
    }

    // horizontale Linien
    for ( y + freier_oberer_rand ; y <= b_y - freier_oberer_rand + b_y_erweitern_um ; y += grid_breite_x_y ) {
      ctx.moveTo( freier_oberer_rand + nach_rechts_verkleinern , d_in + y + freier_oberer_rand);
      ctx.lineWidth = linewidth_1;
      ctx.lineTo( b_x - nach_links_verkleinern + b_x_erweitern_um , d_in + y + freier_oberer_rand );
    }
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.stroke();

    // Pfeile für x
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.moveTo( b_x - nach_links_verkleinern + b_x_erweitern_um + 10, b_y + b_y_erweitern_um );
    ctx.lineTo( b_x - nach_links_verkleinern + b_x_erweitern_um + 5, b_y + b_y_erweitern_um - 2 );
    ctx.lineTo( b_x - nach_links_verkleinern + b_x_erweitern_um + 5, b_y + b_y_erweitern_um + 2 );
    ctx.lineTo( b_x - nach_links_verkleinern + b_x_erweitern_um + 10, b_y + b_y_erweitern_um );
    ctx.fill();
    // Pfeile für y
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo( freier_oberer_rand + nach_rechts_verkleinern , freier_oberer_rand - 10 );
    ctx.lineTo( freier_oberer_rand + nach_rechts_verkleinern + 2 , freier_oberer_rand - 5 );
    ctx.lineTo( freier_oberer_rand + nach_rechts_verkleinern - 2 , freier_oberer_rand - 5 );
    ctx.lineTo( freier_oberer_rand + nach_rechts_verkleinern , freier_oberer_rand - 10 );
    ctx.fill();

    // Bezeichnung x und y
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.font = '10pt Calibri';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';

    ctx.fillText( "y", freier_oberer_rand + nach_rechts_verkleinern - 10, freier_oberer_rand + 2 );
    ctx.fillText( "x", b_x - nach_links_verkleinern + b_x_erweitern_um , b_y + b_y_erweitern_um + 10 );

    var h_font      = 30;
    var p_index_a   = 30;
    var p_index_b   = 90;
    var omega       = "0x03A9";
    var test        = "\\frac{d}{dx}\\left[\\int_a^xf(t)dt\\right]=f(x)";
    var test2       = encodeURIComponent("\\frac{d}{dx}\\left[\\int_a^xf(t)dt\\right]=f(x)");

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.font = '30px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'lime';
    ctx.fillText( "-A", p_index_a, p_index_a );
    ctx.fillText( "Aufprallfläche der Teilchen", p_index_b, p_index_a );
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fillText( "-V", p_index_a, p_index_a*2 );
    ctx.fillText( "Volumen bei d. Impulsion", p_index_b, p_index_a*2 );
  }
  else {
    alert("Dein Browser unterstützt das <canvas> Element nicht");
  }
}
draw();
</script>
```

Comment: Back in [KaTeX PR 251](https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX/pull/251) I had done some work to make my personal fork of KaTeX render to canvas, for the sake of integration with [CindyJS](https://cindyjs.org/) as in [this demo](https://cindyjs.org/examples/katex1.html). I lost track of it since.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you want to do, but if I wanted to show a formula on top of a graph of that formula, I would use the CSS property "z-index" on the DOM element of the formula with a transparent background color and I would position it on top of the canvas where the graph is drawn.

Comment: @MvG Dude. That JS is amazing. It's exactly what i am searching for my next projects. Big thx at you!

Comment: @DominiqueFortin Thx Dude. It would also work, bit thx also to you, but thats not that what i am searching for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Promoting my comment to an answer.*

This answer does not answer your question as stated, but instead offers an alternative for the thing you actually tried to achieve.

Back in [KaTeX pull request 251](https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX/pull/251) I had done some work to make my personal fork of KaTeX render to canvas, for the sake of integration with [CindyJS](https://cindyjs.org/) as in [this demo](https://cindyjs.org/examples/katex1.html).

Main benefit from directly drawing to canvas was that it would integrate nicely with other stuff modifying the canvas, including clipping, layering, transformations, multiple processing steps, saving the whole thing as a single image, and similar. Also, vertically aligning HTML to a well-defined baseline is surprisingly hard.

I lost track of the discussion around my pull request since I posted it. Last I knew there was some plan to develop some intermediate representation which could be layouted on various backends, including HTML+CSS and Canvas. Not sure how much that effort progressed. My PR has been closed as it became fairly outdated.